# External display. "Out of range" after power saving

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, power-management, hdmi

I bought a LG 24MP59G-P 24" monitor and connected to my laptop via HDMI.

It works fine.  And I'm using a "join displays" configuration, having the new monitor as the primary display.

But after power saving "blank screen", it usually stops working and says: "out of range"

Then I have to switch to text mode terminal (CTRL+ALT+F4) and then go back.
Or try to solve it by locking the session, and loging in again.
But it takes several tries to get it working back.
And sometimes I've to unplug the HDMI cable, and connect it again.

I wouldn't like to have to be plugging and unplugging the HDMI cable all the time

Is there any configuration that I could use to avoid these "out of range" failures?

Or, as a workaround, could I solve it using command line?
So I could create a script and a key combination to easily restore it

**Update:**

I tested it using Windows 10 in the same laptop and the problem doesn't reproduce after 20 power savings.  So it seems to be an Ubuntu 20.04 bug, a Nvidia driver bug or a misconfiguration

Answer (score 1):

Two possible work arounds:

- `xrandr` probes display modes and sometimes resets it to a usable one
- `xset dpms force off; xset dpms force on` will force both monitors off and back on, and sometimes this resets things (or maybe it triggers the problem?)

Comment: thanks! the second workaround (force off/on) worked like a charm. xrandr didn't work for me

Comment: I've had xrandr work when the display isn't detected correctly the first time.  It's very situational which of these you need.

Comment: Is there any way to restart only the external monitor?  I tried it by using `xrandr --output HDMI-1-2 --off`
 followed by `xrandr --output HDMI-1-2 --auto`  But it changes the "join displays" configuration to mirror, and even worse, it sometimes triggers the "out of range" error

Comment: Probably not easily.  Note that `xrandr --off` does something very different from `xset dpms force off`; xrandr messes with the display association, as you've found.  xdpms plays with power saving settings only.