# Execute script after returning from power saving black screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, power-management, hdmi, screensaver, pm-utils

I've a issue with my external monitor losing the signal in Ubuntu 20.04.  It doesn't happen using Windows 10.

I found a [workaround here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379506/external-display-out-of-range-after-power-saving) thanks to @user10489  So, I configured Ubuntu to execute `xset dpms force off; xset dpms force on` when pressing CTRL + ALT + R.

But I'd like to execute it automatically after returning from power saving black screen, just by moving the mouse or pressing any key.

Is there any way to handle this event, and add this behaviour using Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Hm, not sure maybe a user systemd.service can handle this.